# Как переименовать элементы ListView. C#, Universal app

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015

Добрый день.

Есть `listview`, нужно при вызове одного из событий (в данном случае двойное нажатие) изменять имя выбранного элемента.

Поясню. В приложение, есть `listview` в него добавляются элементы при нажатие на кнопку, нужно при двойному нажатию на созданный элемент начать редактировать его содержимое.

В Windows Forms делалось это не сложно... А вот в Universal app, не получатся как раньше.

Код объявления `listView`:

```
 <ListView x:Name="PassList" Margin="0,46,0,0" Grid.Row="1" DisplayMemberPath="" DoubleTapped="PassList_DoubleTapped" IsItemClickEnabled="True"/>
```

Ну и на всякий случай кнопка добавляющая элементы в `listview`:

```
public class NamePassPage
{
    public string PassName { get; set; }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.PassName;
    }
}

private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.PassList.Items.Add(new NamePassPage { PassName = "PassPage" });
    }
```

Comment: А в чём вопрос? Как подписаться на событие? Как поменять данные в DataContext'е?

Comment: Ну отлично, а что у вас уже есть? Покажите код.

Comment: Добавил код listview и кнопки.

Comment: Эээ... А почему не через ItemsSource? И что означает «начать редактировать содержимое»? Как это должно выглядеть? (Кроме того: `Margin="0,46,0,0"` — ужас, `DisplayMemberPath=""` — зачем?)

Comment: Почему не через ItemSource, сложно сказать... Но думаю из-за не очень большого опыта разработки не консольных приложений.
Ну в моем представление оно должно выглядеть, как обычное переименование папки, два раза быстро тыкнул на элемент, он переходит в режим изменения надписи.  Как-то так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, для начала вам нужно отделить контент от представления, и завести VM.

Класс `NamePassPage` подходит для этого, только нужно имплементировать `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
class NamePassPage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string passName;
    public string PassName
    {
        get { return passName; }
        set { if (passName != value) { passName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Теперь неплохо бы иметь главный контейнер данных, содержащий список:

```
class MainVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<NamePassPage> Passes { get; private set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<NamePassPage>();
}
```

Теперь, вы скармливаете экземпляр `MainVM` как `DataContext` вашему главному окну/Frame/что там у вас в Universal App, и подключаете список через `ItemsSource`:

```
<ListView IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Passes}"
          DisplayMemberPath="PassName"/>
```

Это покажет список ваших элементов. Добавим теперь кнопку `Add`. Мы хотим, чтобы добавление происходило в VM, а не во View, поэтому нам нужно имплементировать команду, которая выполнится в нашей VM:

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddNew}">Add</Button>
```

При нажатии на кнопку эта команда выполнится. Команду нужно, понятно, поместить в VM. Для этого класс `MainVM` придётся расширить:

```
class MainVM
{
    public MainVM()
    {
        AddNew = new SimpleRelayCommand(AddDefaultPage);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<NamePassPage> Passes { get; private set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<NamePassPage>();

    public ICommand AddNew { get; private set; }

    // этот код создаёт новый экземпляр NamePassPage, и вызывается при активизации команды
    void AddDefaultPage()
    {
        Passes.Add(new NamePassPage() { PassName = "PassPage" });
    }
}
```

Ну и нам нужно имплементировать класс с командой (обычно он есть в каком-нибудь MVVM-фреймворке, но вдруг вы пишете вручную):

```
public class SimpleRelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action execute = null;

    public SimpleRelayCommand(Action execute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        this.execute = execute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return true; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute();
    }
}
```

С этим в список по нажатию на кнопку будут добавляться элементы.

Дальнейшее зависит от того, что вам нужно. Если при двойном клике должно открываться редактирование элемента, пробросьте двойной клик в `MainVM` через команду, и там откройте отдельный UI для редактирования. Если вам нужно inline-редактирование, вам придётся написать кастомный `ItemTemplate` для вашего `ListView`.

Удачи!

Comment: @TheJokiv: Пожалуйста! Получилось у вас с самим изменением?

Comment: Пока только разобрался в коде и начинаю разбираться с MVVM, но в общем я понял, что и как. Доделаю и отпишусь)